# How to actually set a maxlength for textarea field in contact form

Tags: forms, emails

I need to limit the textarea message of the core module contact form to a certain number of characters.

Here are the facts

1. The Form API does not allow one to set a maxlength on textarea field types [while plain HTML does]
2. The [Maxlength](https://drupal.org/project/maxlength) module , doesn't allow you to actually set a maximum length. It gets its max length from the field's max length, defined on each content type's manage field section
3. Creating a new form element type using hook_element_info, still doesn't gurantee I can add the `#maxlength` to the textarea. Besides if I succeed I need to alter again the contact form module to overrride actual message textarea field with mine.

So I can I alter it plain and straightforward?

What is the best idea to alter all textarea fields in the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly off I defined a setting form, then made a hook form alter:

```
function contact_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'contact_site_form') {
    $maximum_limit = (int) variable_get('contact_form_maxlength', 500);
    if($maximum_limit && is_numeric($maximum_limit)) {
    $form['message']['#title'] = $form['message']['#title'] . t(' (maximum @max characters)', array( '@max' => $maximum_limit));
    $form['message']['#maxlength'] = $maximum_limit ;
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to be working fine.

Comment: Just as an aside, you could implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter and save the form ID check, ie: contact_form_form_contact_site_form_alter. Bit of a mouthful as a function name, admittedly.

Comment: That is a great idea. I don't have this habit :-)

Answer (score 6):

> The Form API does not allow to set a maxlength on textarea field types [while plain HTML does]

That's not strictly true....HTML5 introduced a maxlength property for textareas, previous versions do not have it (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

The default templates that come with Drupal 7 all use XHTML, so the lack of explicit support for HTML5 makes perfect sense.

As long as your doctype *is* HTML5, this will probably work:

```
$form['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#attributes' => array('maxlength' => 200),
);
```

Comment: Clive I actually found a working solution, I posted it below. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module like this, put both #maxlength and #maxlength_js properties on the elements you want to control.

```
$form['comments'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Comments'),
  '#maxlength_js' => TRUE,
  '#maxlength' => 1000,
);
```